# ASCII-Import, how to replace comma by dot

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I have some ASCII-data-tables and for some odd reason there are commas(as decimal mark) instead of dots in the last row. Consider for example:

```
asciidata=2  1.25E-01  -6.7E-04  -1,6E-05
```

So when I try to import it to mathematica, I don't get a list with the desired 4 numbers. I tried to use

```
Import["asciidata","table","NumberPoint" -> ","]
```

but then the last number in the example would read -1.6E-05 which I can't get to work for further calculations. 
What is the correct way to do this?

Here is a short part of the data if this helps

```
1   0.000000E+00    -7.147784E-04   -3,263987E-04   
2   1.250000E-01    -6.705654E-04   -1,659138E-05
3   2.500000E-01    -6.783623E-04   -3,556275E-05
4   3.750000E-01    -6.636996E-04   -4,519190E-05
5   5.000000E-01    -6.662689E-04   -4,363282E-05
6   6.250000E-01    -6.776148E-04   -6,221215E-05
7   7.500000E-01    -6.863516E-04   -7,101356E-05
8   8.750000E-01    -6.236293E-04   -1,531795E-04
9   1.000000E+00    -6.317795E-04   -1,714623E-04
10  1.125000E+00    -7.069558E-04   -1,841985E-04
```

Comment: `StringReplace`?

Comment: Some of your data is being read as strings.  Try this:  `ToExpression@Import["asciidata", "table", "NumberPoint" -> ","]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This loads the file "asciidata" as text, replaces every comma by a dot and then imports the result as a table.

```
ImportString[
 StringReplace[Import["asciidata", "Text"], "," -> "."],
 "Table", "NumberPoint" -> "."
 ]
```

Comment: thank you so much! didn't know about ImportString…

Comment: You're welcome!